# scrollIntoView. Не могу перейти

Tags: vue.js, прокрутка

День добрый. как с помощью scroll перейти к другому vue. к определённому блоку.[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQu7H.png)

Answer (score 0):

На скриншоте не видно ваш ref элемент, к которому вы хотите скроллить.
Суть метода такова, вызываете метод *weddingDateClick*, с помощью клика по кнопке,  и скролите до нужного элемента, но  $refs видит только те элементы, которые находятся в этом же компоненте, а не во всем проекте.